# Unit test a custom collection created by a lots of logic

Tags: unit-testing

I have a Factory class with a Create method that takes 8 parameters.

All these 8 parameters are used in combination inside the Create method.

The Create method returns a custom collection.

The custom collection as result needs to be compared to other collections somehow  which I

have passed also to the Create method. But I can not make an 1:1 comparison of the custom

collection. I would have to filter,drill down , sort etc... things to get a successfull

Assert...

I know well about unit testing but I am clueless about testing such a scenario without bringing much logic into the Assertion itself what I actually want to avoid.

As the Create method returns a collection of "Days" for a calendar I can not do manual tests of single days I have to test the whole collection. Edge cases tests are not enough.

**UPDATE**

I put here a sample which is the easiest one of my samples that you get an understanding...

My other unit test (not done) will be way harder as my date range is bigger that means much

assertions and the logic to test increases.

```
[Test]
        public void CreatePeriods_3TimeTablesWithin7VisibleDays_21Periods()
        {
            // ARRANGE
            IDateService dateService = new DateService();
            LessonplannerFactory factory = new LessonplannerFactory(dateService);

            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 03, 01);
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 03, 15);

            String schoolclassCode1 = "BIO1";
            String schoolclassCode2 = "BIO2";
            String schoolclassCode3 = "BIO3";

            IEnumerable<TimeTable> timetableA = new List<TimeTable> { 
                new TimeTable { LessonNumber = 3, SchoolclassCodeMonday = schoolclassCode3, WeekTypeState = TimeTable.WeekType.A },
                new TimeTable { LessonNumber = 2, SchoolclassCodeMonday = schoolclassCode2, WeekTypeState = TimeTable.WeekType.A }, 
                new TimeTable { LessonNumber = 1, SchoolclassCodeMonday = schoolclassCode1, WeekTypeState = TimeTable.WeekType.A }, 
            };

            TimeTable.WeekType selectedWeekType = TimeTable.WeekType.A;
            TimeTable.WeekType startWeekType = TimeTable.WeekType.A;
            DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
            IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> visibleWeekDays = new List<DayOfWeek> { DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Monday };

            int numberOfVisibleDays = 7; int numberOfTimeTables = 3;

            // ACT
            var periods = factory.Create(startDate, endDate, 0, timetableA, null, selectedWeekType, startWeekType, firstDayOfWeek, visibleWeekDays);

            // sort by both properties to make this unit test testable...
            var sortedPeriods = periods.OrderBy(p => p.LessonNumber).ThenBy(p => p.LessonDate);

            // ASSERT

            Assert.IsTrue(periods.Count() == numberOfTimeTables * numberOfVisibleDays);

            // LessonNumber 1
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(0).LessonNumber, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(1).LessonNumber, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(2).LessonNumber, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(3).LessonNumber, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(4).LessonNumber, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(5).LessonNumber, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(6).LessonNumber, 1);

            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(0).SchoolclassCode, string.Empty);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(1).SchoolclassCode, string.Empty);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(2).SchoolclassCode, schoolclassCode1);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(3).SchoolclassCode, string.Empty);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(4).SchoolclassCode, string.Empty);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(5).SchoolclassCode, schoolclassCode1);
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(6).SchoolclassCode, string.Empty);

            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(0).LessonDate, new DateTime(2013, 03, 01));
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(1).LessonDate, new DateTime(2013, 03, 03));
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(2).LessonDate, new DateTime(2013, 03, 04));
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(3).LessonDate, new DateTime(2013, 03, 08));
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(4).LessonDate, new DateTime(2013, 03, 10));
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(5).LessonDate, new DateTime(2013, 03, 11));
            Assert.AreEqual(sortedPeriods.ElementAt(6).LessonDate, new DateTime(2013, 03, 15));

            // LessonNumber 2
            // do the same as above

            // LessonNumber 3  
            // do the same as above
        }
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of what the method looks like with some sample inputs and expected outputs? This would help determine how/if the problem can be decomposed.

Comment: I added a sample now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to break up the code to "Create" into smaller pieces.  Having so many parameters into the function is usually a sign of mixing too many pieces of functionality into one object.

If you can divide the work into smaller object, you can test each objects functionality easier, and then your higher level test can be used to just make sure that you are delegating the work to all of the smaller objects correctly.

Comment: There is nothing to break up actually. Even for the most easy if clause inside the Create method I get a collection where I have to do custom logic in the Assert that ranges often from 30 days to 365 days(year) and compare this with the created collection which has filtered/reshaped data. I can not split the Create logic in multiple public methods that would not make sense in OOP terms and I would just split an if/else into 2 methods which makes no better testability.

Comment: Well, if you can't refactor the code to make it easier to test, I would suggest building up an object for your test suite that you can use to do the complicated logic assertions.  That way, you only have to code the assertion logic once, and can reuse it in all of your test scenarios.

The main thing to focus in that case would be making the test assertion object easy to "read", so that the tests remain clear to future developers.

Comment: Yes I just created a base test class for all repetitive stuff.

Comment: I will tommorrow still post a unit test which is the easiest one of all but still complicated what I do not like.

Comment: I thought again about your advise. And I broke... the code now into LessonplannerAFactory and LessonplannerBFactory. These will at least eason the setup of the unit test data because I have not to pass unneeded stuff etc... Thanks